# How to get multiple documents with a search on server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to fetch all documents that has a particular information.

Let's say, these are the documents:

```
{name: "doc1", info: ["x","y","z","t"]}
{name: "doc2", info: ["x","y","a","b"]}
{name: "doc3", info: ["q","w","e","r"]}
```

I want to get the documents that has `"y"` in the info array.
In the mongo shell I can achieve this easily with `find()`:

```
db.collection.find({info: "y"})
```

The code above gives me both doc1 and doc2:

```
{name: "doc1", info: ["x","y","z","t"]}
{name: "doc2", info: ["x","y","a","b"]}
```

However, the same approach doesn't work that way on Meteor server.
Is there an equivalent code to do this on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine in the meteor, May be you are missing something.
For that you have a create a instance of you mongodb collection. like

> y = new Mongo.Collection('collection_name')

Then you you can find and insert data info db using y variable.
Like this
[image]

Comment: What missing was `fetch()`. Thanks a lot!